# Spring Data JPA: Specification

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Мне нужно составить через спецификации запрос, в котором я исключу из выборки несколько ID.

Сделал я это так:

```
case "not_in":
    ArrayList<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(
            Arrays
                    .stream(filter.getValue().toString().split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
     );
     predicate = criteriaBuilder.not(root.get(filter.getField())).in(list);
     break;
```

По итогам составления спецификации, я ожидаю увидеть запрос, похожий на такой:

```
select generatedAlias0 
from ru.gamble.main.domain.AuthLog as generatedAlias0 
    where generatedAlias0.userId not in (11523666) 
order by generatedAlias0.dateTime desc
```

Формируется следующий запрос:

```
select generatedAlias0 
from ru.gamble.main.domain.AuthLog as generatedAlias0 
    where generatedAlias0.userId <> true in (11523666) 
order by generatedAlias0.dateTime desc
```

В принципе, запрос рабочий, и если его выполнить в консоли как скрипт, он исполнится нормально. Но в случае с Hibernate, выдаёт следующее:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
    unexpected AST node: 
    in near line 1, column 115 
    [select generatedAlias0 from ru.main.domain.AuthLog as generatedAlias0 
    where generatedAlias0.userId <> true in (11523666)
    order by generatedAlias0.dateTime desc]
```

Есть идеи, как это решить?

```
HIBERNATE_VERSION = "4.3.10.Final"
SPRING_DATA_VERSION = "1.11.10.RELEASE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следите за скобками:

```
criteriaBuilder.not(root.get(filter.getField())).in(list); // Ваш вариант
criteriaBuilder.not(root.get(filter.getField()).in(list)); // Правильный вариант
```

В вашем варианте отрицание применяется только к операнду `root.get(filter.getField())`, а надо применять его ко всему выражению `root.get(filter.getField()).in(list)`.